# Rep audit shows rep from suggested edits, but I never did an edit without full edit privileges

Tags: support, reputation, suggested-edits

My detailed reputation audit (the one accessible at https://stackoverflow.com/reputation) shows the following note at the end:

> earned 22 reputation out of a maximum of 1000 from suggested edits

However, when this suggested edit system was put in place, I already had full edit privileges. Because of that I never made an edit that went into the suggested edit queue. How is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your "Suggestions" activity here:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/46642/r-martinho-fernandes?tab=activity&sort=suggestions

Those are tag wiki edits, which you did do, and did get you some nice rep. Check out your rep for Aug. 24th for example.

Comment: You get the accept for the link :)

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you made a number of tag wiki edits, which would have had to been reviewed if you were below 20k reputation at the time, and therefore would have counted as suggested edits.

Comment: Ah, I forgot about tag wiki edits. That should be it.